# User meta query results in PHP notice: only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: meta-query, users

I am using a URL rewrite to put the user's display name in the URL to display a user profile.  This part all works fine and the proper value is passed through the query_vars and I can get the correct user.

Since this is for a plugin, some plugin users may want to use the user's first/last name instead of the display name.  I've set up an opportunity for them to do that where the first/last name is separated by an underscore(_).

To retrieve the user when the URL rewrite is passing the query_var "display_name", I am using a meta query in `get_users()`.

```
// Get the custom query_var value.
$query_var = get_query_var( 'display_name' );

/**
 * When the display_name query_var is first name/last name,
 * (for example "john_smith"), split the value by unscore 
 * to get the individual first and last name values.
 */
$pieces = explode( '_', $query_var );

// User meta query to get the user ID by first_name/last_name.
$user = reset( get_users( array(
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'=>'first_name',
            'value' => $pieces[0],
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'last_name',
            'value' => $pieces[1],
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'number' => 1,
    'count_total' => false
) ) );
```

The meta query works fine and the correct user ID is returned, ***but*** I get a PHP notice as follows:

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference

The line indicated is the meta query line `$user = reset( get_users( array(`

Any thoughts on what is wrong and is throwing the PHP notice?  Any ideas on a better query to get the user ID by first name/last name meta keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value passed to [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) is [passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), which means technically it modifies the original variable that's passed to it. For this to work you need to pass a variable, not a function that returns a value.

> **reset()** rewinds **array's** internal pointer to the first element and
>   returns the value of the first array element.

All you need to do is assign the returned value if `get_users()` to a variable and then use `reset()` on *that*:

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'meta_query'  => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'=>'first_name',
            'value' => $pieces[0],
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'last_name',
            'value' => $pieces[1],
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'number' => 1,
    'count_total' => false
) );

$user = reset( $users );
```

Comment: Doh! I was definitely looking in the wrong place (looking at get_users())!  Thanks for the answer - worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = reset( get_users( array(
```

The function `reset()` changes the passed variable, hence it needs a reference. Function output of `get_users()` can't be referenced because it is not a variable. Just assign the return value to a variable and call that:

```
$users = get_users( array(
    //...
) );
$user = reset( $users );
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! And it does work (which is why I upvoted it). It's the same as Jacob's - the primary reasons I accepted his were (1) it was posted first (but by only a minute), but (2) he has a little more explanation with php doc links.